# Module parse failed: Unexpected token Emberjs

Tags: typescript, ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli, rollup

I currently have an issue in an addon which I'm trying to convert to an Emberjs addon to the V2 version. It's a component addon with the co-location layout and  typescript in it. Something goes wrong with the compilation of the typescript giving me this error for basically every file:
[Error without type declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIkFr.png)

The error displayed above is when I disable the declaration of ts files in the rollup config. If I turn it on it'll give this error:
[Error with type declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXDfW.png)

I've already checked the rollup and babel config may times so far and haven't been able to find anything particularly wrong. I was wondering if anybody could help with this, I've been stuck on it for a few days now.
This is the addon rollup.config.js

```
// @ts-nocheck
import ts from 'rollup-plugin-ts';
import { Addon } from '@embroider/addon-dev/rollup';
import { defineConfig } from 'rollup';

const addon = new Addon({
  srcDir: 'src',
  destDir: 'dist',
});

export default defineConfig({
  output: addon.output(),
  plugins: [
    addon.publicEntrypoints([
      'classes/*.js',
      'components/**/*.js',
      'helpers/*.js',
      'services/*.js',
      'transforms/*.js',
    ]),

    addon.appReexports([
      'components/**/*.js',
      'helpers/*.js',
      'services/*.js',
      'transforms/*.js',
    ]),

    ts({
      transpiler: 'babel',
      browserslist: ['last 2 firefox versions', 'last 2 chrome versions'],
      tsconfig: {
        fileName: 'tsconfig.json',
        hook: (config) => ({
          ...config,
          declaration: false,
          declarationMap: true,
          declarationDir: './dist',
        }),
      },
    }),

    addon.dependencies(),

    addon.hbs(),

    addon.keepAssets(['**/*.css']),

    addon.clean(),
  ],
});
```

This is the babel.config,js

```
const { resolve } = require;

module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
  plugins: [
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-transform-typescript'),
      {
        allowDeclareFields: true,
        onlyRemoveTypeImports: true,
        // Default enums are IIFEs
        optimizeConstEnums: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators'),
      {
        // The stage 1 implementation
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
      {
        // Only support browsers that also support class properties...
        // If all addons do this, it greatly reduces shipped JS
      },
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
    resolve('@embroider/addon-dev/template-colocation-plugin'),
    resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'),
  ],
  assumptions: {
    // For legacy decorator support with class fields to work
    setPublicClassFields: true,
    privateFieldsAsProperties: true,
  },
};
```

this is the tsconfig.json

```
const { resolve } = require;
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
  plugins: [
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-transform-typescript'),
      {
        allowDeclareFields: true,
        onlyRemoveTypeImports: true,
        // Default enums are IIFEs
        optimizeConstEnums: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators'),
      {
        // The stage 1 implementation
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
      {
        // Only support browsers that also support class properties...
        // If all addons do this, it greatly reduces shipped JS
      },
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
    resolve('@embroider/addon-dev/template-colocation-plugin'),
    resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'),
  ],
  assumptions: {
    // For legacy decorator support with class fields to work
    setPublicClassFields: true,
    privateFieldsAsProperties: true,
  },
};
```

The addon is also open source so anything else can be found at: https://gitlab.com/getflights/ember-field-components

Comment: is your code importing a type without the `import type` syntax?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I don't believe it is but I can't be completely sure. Is there any way that i can check this?

Comment: In all your tsconfigs, add: 

importsNotUsedAsValues: 'error'

Comment: Did this and updated it everywhere, didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: did you ever figure out your issue?

Comment: I have not yet figured it out.